# Android ListView: getTag() returns null

Tags: android, listview, null

Hallo all,

I have a ListView which contains a Button in each line. The following code is part of the getView() Method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        TextView tv;
        Button saveA_button;
        EditText edittext;
        FITB_ViewWrapper wrapper;

  if (row == null) {
       LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       if (ChooseMode_Act.modeInfo.equalsIgnoreCase("Training")) { 
             row = li.inflate(R.layout.exercise_for_training_fitb,parent, false);
       }else {
              row = li.inflate(R.layout.exercise_for_exam_fitb,parent, false);
       }
       wrapper=new FITB_ViewWrapper(row);
       row.setTag(wrapper);
       if (ChooseMode_Act.modeInfo.equalsIgnoreCase("Exam")) {
           saveA_button=wrapper.getSaveAnswer_Button();
           OnClickListener l=new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                     Integer mp=(Integer)v.getTag();
                     Log.i("mp","my Position is: "+mp);
               }
          };
          saveA_button.setOnClickListener(l);
       }
   }else {
           wrapper=(FITB_ViewWrapper) row.getTag();
 }
```

For my App i need to known to which item the Button belongs to, so i try to detect it. The code

```
Log.i("mp","my Position is: "+mp);
```

puts out a message:    mp   myPosition is: null

I can't understand, why do i get a "null" but not an Integer? How can i find out the Position of an Item in a ListView?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log.i("mp","my Position is: "+position);

you have the position already !

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

Comment: Oh, yeah!  Its still good to understand how ListViews work as I described in my answer, but this seems like the easier solution.  There is no need to be messing around with tags when you already have the position.

Answer (score 0):

The Views in a ListView are reused as you scroll up and down.  Thus, setting values in getView often has unintented consequences, like the image that you meant to set for item number 5 appearing in item number 10, 15 and 20 also.

To avoid this, if you want to set properties in getView you need to make sure you set or unset them for each view.

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish with your code, but it might help to move the setTag outside of the if statement, to make sure you are setting it each time that a view is used.

Comment: You are right, the rows are reused as one scroll up and down. In my App, each ListView Item contains a question(TextView) and an EditText, one should be able to enter his answer in this EditText View. Now i can enter my answer in the EditText View, e.g in row 5. But each time i scroll through the ListView and come back to the Item again, my answer is gone or displayed in a wrong row, e.g row 10. So i try to add a Button View in each row. If one clicks on the button, the user input in the edittext view should be saved into an Array. But it also doesn't work. Cause i can't detect the right row.

Comment: What i want is just to let the user input display correctly and save the user input into an Array, no matter how the user scroll up and down through the listview. I have tried more than a week to solve this problem, but with no Success. Please help me! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try Jorgesys's suggestion for finding the row? Rather than storing info in the tag, just use the position that is provided as a function paramater.

Comment: yes, i have tried Jorgesys's suggestion for finding the row. But it did not work. I think this position parameter woks correctly just wenn the rows in the listview doesn't contain any interactive component like button and radiogroup. If the rows contain interactive components, one have to use setTag() and getTag() method to make them work correctly. One strange thing is that, i can make radiogroup in listview rows work correctly by using getTag() and setTag() method, but no for button. Because v.getTag() method in my question above returns a null value. I don't understand why. Thank you.

Comment: to get the position must be inside the getview function not inside the button listener: public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Log.i("mp","my Position is: "+position);
and then tag that value to your element

Comment: Thank you very much Mayra and Jorgesys! I have solve the problem in another way, cause time is tight. But i will try out your solution.

Comment: Hallo Jorgesys. I had to use ListView again with CheckBox in each Item. So i have tried your solution and it works well. Thank you very much.